# Why does cygwin rebaseall run like a dog?

Tags: cygwin

If you install cygwin these days it runs "rebaseall" as part of its post installation process. This is apparently to realign dlls in some way so that you don't get errors in fork().

At this point in the process the install looks like it has hung for me, both with 32bit and 64bit cygwin. However, if I wait long enough (say 3 hours) the install will finish. At this point the computer runs like a dog - any new process takes forever to start and I have to reboot. If I do this then all is then fine until I try and install something else at which point the whole process kicks off again.

The install is doing something weird to my computer. I have tried closing all applications, removing software - all yield the same result. I have heard others complaining about this but seen no answers other than it must be some thirdy party software. To me this looks like a bug in cygwin.
Incidentally while the install hang is going on I can see dash processes starting and stopping in task manager - so something is happening but really slowly.
Any ideas?

Comment: Running something like AppSense?

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer my own question. The issue was Trusteer Rapport. This piece of software beloved by banks, causes all sorts of bad side effects including this one.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a programming question.
It is also borderline on http://superuser.com.

A normal update postinstall autorebase step take few minutes. Likely you have some software interfering like an antivirus.

Further reading:

```
https://cygwin.com/problems.html
https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda
```

and ask support on the cygwin mailing list

```
https://cygwin.com/lists.html
```

Comment: Yeah read all those. Do not have any of that software. Closed apps and the issue still occurs. I have seen other folk ask the same question on the cygwin mailing list and just give the answer you did.